# Google Chrome wont play Youtube, Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, youtube

When I go to play a Youtube video it suggests I download the latest flash player. However, when I go to download the player it states that the latest version is installed, and won't let me download the player. Any fix's for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought maybe someone had made a better solution by now, but I can't seem to find it.

[Moving the plugin manually from your Firefox installation should still work, though.](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-enable-adobes-flash-player-in-google-chrome-ubuntu-9.04-p2)

Answer (score 2):

install flash player locally or re-install google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://maketecheasier.com/enable-flash-support-in-google-chrome-in-ubuntu/2009/08/19). It may help you.

But I was able to use Flash Player normally when I installed Chrome. I am running Ubuntu 10.04. The process explained there is a bit complicated. I'd suggest you try reinstalling Chrome.